# Mann-Whitney on absence data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mean, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I don’t have a strong background in mathematics or statistics so please forgive me if some of my observations don’t make sense.

I have some HR data about absences from work and I want to test some hypothesis such as “does rewards (extra money) impact on absences?” or “does the size of the office impact on absences?” and so on.
So for example I split my data in people that had a reward and those who didn’t and computed means of absence hours for each. I got this:

6969 ppl with no reward - 336 mean hours of absence

819 ppl with a reward - 309 mean hours of absence

At this point I performed a Mann-Whitney U test to check if there’s a statistically significant difference between the two means and to possibly assume that there’s some sort of association between getting a reward and being absent from work.

My output is something like Mann Whitney U = 2668312,500000 and Sig. 2 tails 0,000
so I would interpret that there’s a statistically significant difference between the two populations.

My questions are: is this legit? and, could I have concluded this also without the test? I mean: it is clear that 336 and 309 are two different numbers..
I feel that there’s something I’m missing..

Comment: Might I ask which software you are using in order to run the test? The way you are quoting the results seems a bit off, namely the "U = 2668312,500000 and Sig. 2 tails 0,000"

Comment: The Mann-Whitney test does not usually test a hypothesis about the means.

Comment: For your analysis to be valuable, you will need to go beyond the hypothesis test.  Since you have a large sample size (total of almost 8000), you will likely get a significant p-value even for a small effect.  You could use an effect size statistic (Vargha and Delaney's *A*, or others, for MW).  But ultimately you will have to decide if the difference is of practical importance.  Is a difference of 27 hours meaningful? Only you or your audience can decide.